# How to distinguish "more and more" and "further"

Tags: adverbs

Could you think of a sentence or situation where we could use the following interchangeably?

> more and more
>
> further

Comment: And keep the meaning? The first examples that come to mind are ones where they can be swapped but where swapping them changes the meaning.

Comment: my guess is that `further` implies direction (a vector). Therefore you say `go further`. Meantime `more` speaks about volume, which has no direction. Occasionally, you do not bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are some cases.  Let's take Caroffrey's examples and rearrange them a bit:

- As the excavator kept digging more and more, he became more confident of finding something.
- As the excavator kept digging further, he became more confident of finding something.

(Equivalent)

But, one might argue that the first sentence should say "farther", not "further", as it speaks of a physical distance.

---

Of course, in most cases they are not interchangeable; one sounds funny.

- These days you hear about the internet more and more.
- These days you hear about the internet further.

(Not Equivalent)

---

And in some cases the substitution is beyond peculiar:

- To further your understanding, you should read this book.
- To more and more your understanding, you should read this book.

(Not even close—not even grammatically possible!)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

> The ***more and more*** the excavator kept digging, the more confident he
>   became of finding something.
>
> The ***further*** the excavator kept digging, the more confident he became
>   of finding something.

Comment: Your use of **more and more** is not idiomatic (at least not in AmE). "The more the excavator kept digging..." would be correct.

Comment: How do you know that you should use `more` in the second clause?

Comment: You appear to be mixing up two phrases: ["more and more"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+and+more) which means "increasingly", the other ["the more... the more"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+more+the+more) describing a positive connotation between two things.